# ASP.net if else FluentValidation condition

Tags: c#, asp.net, fluentvalidation

I tried to do if else condition in Fluent Validation, I found that Fluent Validation have `When` `Otherwise` , now my `Type` is equal to 2, so it should go for `do something B`, but it keep go in to `do something A`

```
When(x => x.Type == 1, () => {
    //do something A
}).Otherwise(() => {
    //do something B
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You will notice that the debug point is indeed going into both the blocks but errors are not shown for the same.

For example following code,

```
        When(x => x.Type == 1, () =>
        {
            RuleFor(y => y.Type).LessThanOrEqualTo(1);
        })
        .Otherwise(() => {
            RuleFor(y => y.Type).GreaterThan(10);
        });
```

will work for Type = 1 (i.e. no error will be shown) but for Type = 0 and Type = 2 (to 10), the following error will be shown:

```
{
    "Type": [
        "'Type' must be greater than '10'."
    ]
}
```